# Javolution Struct optimizations/config tuning tips?

Tags: java, disruptor-pattern, javolution

I'm using a Javolution Struct class for the events in a Disruptor ring buffer - it seemed the easiest way of making my messages more cache friendly.
I have no previous experience with Javolution, though, and have found very little material regarding tutorials on tuning Javolution.

My questions are:

1. What are the drawbacks I should be aware of with this approach (i.e., with using Javolution Structs as event classes)?
2. Are there any Javolution-specific optimizations I should be aware of?
   The only tuning parameter I've found and used so far is:

   @Override public boolean isPacked() {
        return true; 
   }

Thanks in advance

**-- EDIT --**

Give or take, the class looks like this:

```
public class DisruptorEvent extends Struct {
    Signed8 field1 = new Signed8();
    Signed32 field2 = new Signed32();
    Signed64 field3 = new Signed64();
    Signed64 field4 = new Signed64();
    Signed64 field5 = new Signed64();
    Signed32 field6 = new Signed32();

    @Override
    public boolean isPacked() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to packaing, you should also take care of byteOrder(), return big/little endian.

Note that javolution `Struct` use ByteBuffer and not byte[]. Its not very clear to me whether you need serialization or not, but if you do, make sure you work on ByteBuffers that's been "rewinded"